# How to cast class object to interface

Tags: java, class, interface, casting

I have an    `interface Home`    and a    `class HomeClass implements Home`    .

How can i cast object of    `HomeClass`   into    `Home`    ?

Comment: Home home = (Home) homeClass? I don't think you even need to cast it. Should be implicit.

Comment: You don't have to cast it at all. Can you post an example of your code that way we can see what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Levan if any of the answer works, mark as an answer and upvote :)

Comment: As long as HomeClass implements the Home interface, as noted, no cast is required.  Consider reading this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to cast anything. You can simply use `Home obj = new HomeClass()`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast it. In this situation:

```
Object bar = new HomeClass();
Home x = bar;
```

Java can't give you guarantee, that bar is really HomeClass. And it will notice you: `Incompatible types`. In bar can be anything, so you must cast it. In this:

```
HomeClass bar = new HomeClass();
Home x = bar;
```

Compiler can be really sure, that bar can be only `HomeClass` or `? extends` HomeClass (they must implements Home)